# Which class name has to be inserted for generic in this situation?

Tags: java, list, class, object, generics

I am writing a code about mafia game. but I have a big problem that isn't solvable by myself.

There are Mafia, Police, Doctor and Citizen classes. the name is not important.

and Every Mafia, Police, Doctor, Citizen extends Player class.

Then I need to put these object objected by these classes to List.

```
Mafia mafia = new Mafia();
Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
Police police = new Police();
Citizen citizen = new Citizen();

List players<  ?  > = new ArrayList();

players.add(mafia);
players.add(doctor);
players.add(police);
players.add(citizen);
```

For above code working well, which Class name does have to be written in <  ?  > at above code.

the list named 'player' has to be able to contain several classes that extend same class.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the list (players) and the superclass of those objects (xxx extends Player) already be sufficient to know that type to use?

Comment: You can write like `List<? extends Player> players = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elaborating on Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236388/elaborating-on-polymorphism)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and Every Mafia, Police, Doctor, Citizen extends Player class.

You basically gave the answer yourself.

`List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();`